Sign Issues with Quantization of real Klein-Gordon Field
Why in second quantization of real Klein-Gordon field
$$
\phi_{real}(x)=\int \frac{d^3 p}{(2\pi)^3}\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\omega_p}}(\hat{a}_p e^{ipx}+\hat{a}_p ^\dagger e^{-ipx})\
$$
is $\hat{a}_p ^\dagger$ is the creation operator and  $\hat{a}_p$ annihilation and not say the other way round? ( Rmk.: To avoid potential confusions I work through with conventional $(+,-,-,-)$ metric for $4$- product $p \cdot x$.
The point is that nearly every script I read so far on quatization of KG claims this without loosing one word why
on regards $\hat{a}_p ^\dagger$ creation and $\hat{a}_p $ annihilation without explaining actually why. So is it just a convention or can it be derived as logical consequence from certain "input assumptions"?
Surely one could pose identical question for complex KG field with $2$ sorts of particles
$$
\phi_{cpx}(x)=\int \frac{d^3 p}{(2\pi)^3}\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\omega_p}}(\hat{a}_p e^{ipx}+\hat{b}_p ^\dagger e^{-ipx})\
$$
why $\hat{b}_p ^\dagger$ is creator and $\hat{a}_p $ annihilator and not conversely? Is there a "clear" reason for it is this just a matter of convention?
#UPDATE: As @naturallyInconsistent in a comment below suggested it seems that the issue sits in neccessarity to match the commutation relation with the "right" sign in the exponential, right? But which sign is actually the "right one" and how to deduce it? More precisely, where in the construction it becomes unambiguous to which sign belongs the creation operator and to which annihilation? That's the issue.
Say we start with Fourier expansion of our field $
\phi_{real}(x)=\int \frac{d^3 p}{(2\pi)^3}\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\omega_p}}(a_p e^{ipx}+ a_p ^\dagger e^{-ipx}) $ and want to perform canonical quantization on it - so by promoting the coefficients $a_p$ & $a_p ^\dagger$ to pair of creation & annihilation operators subjected to commutation and not anticommutation bracket relation.
At which stage in the construction it becomes unambiguous to which of the exponential factors should belong the creation and to which the annihilation operator? In other words - why Fourier coefficient $a_p$ in above expansion should be promoted unambigouly to annihilation and $a_p ^\dagger$ to creation and not say in another way? What makes this assigning "choiceless" (assuming only that we use $(+,-,-,-)$ metric)?
Following Prasad's argument we are done once knowing $[a_p,a_q^\dagger] = \delta(p-q)$ by "drawing analogy" to quantization of harmonic oscillator. But that's what we need to deduce, not declare definitionally, as otherwise we could just rename $c_p:=a_p ^\dagger$, making notion of cretation & annihilation ambiguously, bit that would lead to nonsense as it should be unambiguous to which exponent which operator actually belongs.

When you compute the commutation relations, we find that $[a_p,a_q^\dagger] = \delta(p-q)$, which tells us that $a_p^\dagger$ is a creation operator and $a_p$ is an annihilation operator

Use the commutation relation of the two ladder operators to compute their commutation with the Hamiltonian then you'll see that the creation operator increases the energy while the annihilation operator decreases it.

Note that you have to match the commutation relation with the sign in the exponential. This whole thing is one whole set that you have to derive together, and so textbooks take this as derived. Within there, you have choices of signs in the metric, the canonical quantisation, and so forth, and so conventions also play a rôle.

@Prahar: Let me try to rephrase your idea: So say we start with expansion $ \phi(x)=\int \frac{d^3 p}{(2\pi)^3}\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\omega_p}}(\hat{a}_p e^{ipx}+\hat{a}_p ^\dagger e^{-ipx})\ $ a priori not knowing if $a_p$ is creation or annihlation. Then we can calculate the inversions of $a_p$ and $a_p ^\dagger $ ( ...in following I will leave the "hats" even though we talking about operators) in terms of $\phi$ and $\pi$ - the canon momentum. Ok, then in order to be able to deduce that $[a_p,a_q^\dagger] = \delta(p-q)$, what information we need as input\assumptions?

(cont) That $[\phi(x), \phi(y)]=[\pi(x), \pi(y)]=0$ and $[\phi(x), \pi(y)]=i\delta(x-y)$ and in order to get the "right" sign?

@flippiefanus: But what do we take as "known or assumed input" to conclude what is creation and what annihilation among $a_p$ and $a_p^{\dagger}$? That $H = \int dp^3 c a_p a_p^{\dagger}+a_p^{\dagger} a_p$ ( c>0$) and not the other way round?

@naturallyInconsistent: But to pin down what we take as "conventions" and what can we actually deduce "as logical consequence": I take that we work with $(+,-,-,-)$ metric and that "canonical quantization" is refered to those working with commutation bracket convention $[a,b]=ab-ba$. Starting from this as assumptions and writing down $\phi(x)=\int \frac{d^3 p}{(2\pi)^3}\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\omega_p}}(\hat{a}_p e^{ipx}+\hat{a}_p ^\dagger e^{-ipx})$ as "ansatz" a priori not knowing if $a_p$ or $a_p^{\dagger}$ is creation and vice versa, what do we actually need to assume as input to deduce as

(cont) logical consequence from the assumptions we started with that $a_p^{\dagger}$ takes the role of creation and $a_p$ annihilation and not the other way round? I mean clearly we can rename these to $c_p:= a_p^{\dagger}$ and so on, but the question is  if to exponent $e^{ipx}$ in the expansion above belongs the creation or annihilation op and why not the other way round, assuming we regard the $4$-product $px$ with convention $(+,-,-,-)$?

In other words, at which stage in the construction and why it is crucial to match up the commutation relation with the "right" sign of the exponentials? What is the problem if we do it in another way?

@user267839 - yes, to everything you said to me.

@Prahar: Ok, so to deduce $[a_p,a_q^\dagger] = \delta(p-q)$ the only nontrivial assumption we putting in is really only $[\phi(x), \pi(y)]=i\delta(x-y)$ (...as comming heuristically from classical case) and that the 4-metric has signature $(+,-,-,-)$ (...thats by convention). Ok, assumming we have managed to calculate from this that $[a_p,a_q^\dagger] = \delta(p-q)$. Why can we deduce from this that $a_p$ promotes to annihilator and not the other way round? A guess: by "heuristic comparison" with commutation relations for creation & annihilation op's of usual harmonic operator?

No. It follows by the argument made by @flippiefanus. The Hamiltonian is $H = \sum_p E_p a_p^\dagger a_p$ where $E_p > 0$. From this, it follows that $a_p^\dagger$ increases energy, so it must create a particle. $a_p$ lowers the energy, so it must destroy it.

@Prahar: So once we know that $H = \sum_p E_p a_p^\dagger a_p $ then we indeed get this conclusion. From which assumptions we derive that the Hamilton op $H$ must have this form and not say with flipped $a_p a_p^\dagger $, or eg with summands of form $ E_p ( a_p^\dagger a_p + a_p a_p^\dagger $? Is it also a "heuristical input" of derivable?

@user267839 - The form of $H$ is irrelevant. If you had a term $a_p a_p^\dagger$, we could always use the commutation relation to bring into the form $a_p^\dagger a_p$. Once in that form, the Hamiltonian takes the form $H = \sum_p E_p a_p^\dagger a_p + C$ for some constant $C$. The result is the same at the end of the day.

@Prahar: About one point I'm not completely sure: At the beginning you remarked that we need to show the identity $[a_p,a_q^\dagger] = \delta(p-q)$ (... and once having showed this, the consequent argumentation how to deduce what is creation and what annihil op. I understand so far). But in order to derive this identity, what do we actually need to assume?

Like you said, we assume that $[\phi(x), \pi(y)] = i \delta(x-y)$.

@Prahar: Only? But this assumption comes just as "beeing motivated" from analogy with classical Poisson bracket, not something more "deeper", right?

That bracket is just canonical quantization. No other assumption is needed.
